# How to refresh form to get the new value

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the new value from a field inside my formGroup.  However, the value I got is the previous value not the new value of the field.

Example:

I have a field in the form group `firstname` then I entered `John` to the field, but then I go back and change the FirstName field from `John` to `Paul`, when I do my logic in *.html file, I still got John as first name instead of Paul.

I wonder how to update my form so it got the newly change value?

```
   <my-component *ngIf="formGroup.get('firstname`).value === `John`">
    <div>Hello John</div>
   </my-component>
```

Comment: Better to post all of your .ts and .html.

Comment: What is your changedetection ?